# Some idiomatic explanations

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

- **Tout à fait** directly translated would be '**all to do**', how does this get inferred as '**absolutely**'?
- je m’en fous directly translated would be '**I am in craziness**', how does this get inferred as '**I don't care**'?
- 'Fais gaffe' directly translated would be '**Make/do a blunder**', how does this get inferred as '**Watch out**'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### « Tout à fait »

From http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/fait, "a fait" already meant "absolutely" in ancient French.

### « Je m'en fous »

It's not "fous" as in "crazy" but rather the verb "foutre" (vulgar). 
It's vulgar for "Je m'en moque" (directly translated as "I'm laughing about it")

### « Fais gaffe »

From https://originedesmots.blogspot.fr/2014/02/gaffe.html:
"faire gaffre" means "keep guard" in ancient french

Comment: Thanks! so dont use 'je m'en fous' in formal situations?

Comment: No don't use it! It's the same as "I don't give a shit" I believe.

Answer (score 2):

"tout à fait" can be translasted by absolutely, like "Be Chiller Too" Says.

"Je m'en fous" is pretty familiar. Think about a rough "I don't care"

"Fais gaffe" is equal to "fais attention" but is much familliar. You may translate this by "be careful"